# The image is not from one VC to another VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

The image is not from one VC to another VC.

The problem is displaying it to the image view in the main UIViewController. I have everything hooked up correctly in the Storyboard.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLzJq.png) to view my storyboard layout.

Please note some of my unnecessary code has been removed from both ViewController classes.

**Here is my first UIViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    @IBAction func editPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let ViewController2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddNewEaterySegue") as! ViewController2
        ViewController2.imageForEdit = imageView.image!
        print(imageView)
        print(imageView.image!)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController2, animated: true)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }

}
```

**Here is my second UIViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2:  UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var filter : CIFilter!
    var imageForEdit = UIImage()
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    @IBOutlet weak var select: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageLabel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIImage) {
        if textField.text == "" {
            print("Не все поля заполнены")
        } else {


        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueFromViewController", sender: sender)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageLabel.image = imageForEdit
        print(imageLabel)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func tappedEnter(_ sender: Any) {

        if textField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
            return
        } else {
            if let texttxt = textField.text {

                let data = texttxt.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)

                if select.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
                {
                    filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")
                } else {
                    filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
                }

                filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
                let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)
                let image = UIImage(ciImage: filter.outputImage!.transformed(by: transform))
                imageLabel.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are pushing to ViewController2 your imageView in ViewController is empty.

Where exactly are you setting the image for imageView?

In your storyboard, the imageView in ViewController is empty and also in the didSet method for imageView in ViewController you have not set any image to the imageView.

**Try this in ViewController:**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
    didSet {

        //Add a test image to your project.
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YOUR_TEST_IMAGE_NAME.jpeg")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Ok I guess I was not clear on your question. So in order to send the image from "ViewController2" back to "ViewController", you can use many methods but the way I would do it is by using Protocols.

I have done it in a generic way but you can apply this to send any kind of data from one view controller back to the previous view controller.

**Try this in ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

protocol ImageViewProtocol{
     func sendImageToViewController(theImage: UIImage)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ImageViewProtocol {

    func sendImageToViewController(theImage: UIImage) {
        imageView.image = theImage
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewcontroller2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller2") as! ViewController2
        viewcontroller2.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller2, animated: true)

    }

}
```

**Try this in ViewController2:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var delegate: ImageViewProtocol!

    @IBOutlet weak var barcodeImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        barcodeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "test_image.jpg")

    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate.sendImageToViewController(theImage: barcodeImageView.image!)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't work.

I want to generate barcode and transfer it via the Save button.

From "Viewcontroller2" in "Viewcontroller".

Comment: @DayMan: I have edited my answer. I am sure this will solve your problem. You need to use protocols in order to send data from current view back to previous view. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @DayMan can you send me your project ?? I will try to solve it.

Comment: @DayMan Just to confirm the identifier you are using in this line,
 `let viewcontroller2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller2") as! ViewController2`

this identifier should be the identifier of viewcontroller 2 and not of your segue.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/UltDX0ka2yEU9w 

Here is the project. Please describe in detail the steps.

Comment: @DayMan i have found the solution and corrected your project. Basically you were doing 2 things wrong.
1. You were using the wrong identifier for `ViewController2`. I have added a screen shot in the project folder showing you where to change it.
2. You were using the wrong file name while setting the image to `barcodeImageView`. So i changed that too. These are the only 2 changes i made and the code complies fine. 
Let me know if you are clear on this now.

Comment: @DayMan here is the link to the project
https://www.dropbox.com/s/78ox6vo88zra6so/Code.zip?dl=0

Comment: @DayMan where exactly are you getting "Expected Type" error ?? Because the project i sent you complies fine for me. Did you modify anything in the project i sent you ???

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DayMan If it worked for you and your problem is solved please mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Where to click? (Face palm...)

Comment: @DayMan: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
You should see a small tick mark next to my answer. When you click it, it turns green. Please follow the link for details.

Comment: @DayMan good job. Once you get enough reputations you will be able to upvote also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567729/do-you-want-to-add-protocol-stubs


Please see how the Protocol can be handled properly